# Изменение конфигурации без последствий для обновления

Tags: 1с

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли добавить в форму некот. документов Бухгалтерии 8.2 возможность открытия соотв. файлов сканов этого документа, хранящихся на диске т.о., чтобы потом не было проблем с обновлением, и как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не хотите получать проблемы при обновлении, то используйте самописные внешние отчеты и обработчики. Если хотите, то можете и в конфигурацию их засунуть, но в таком случае при обновлении в окне сравнения просто укажите, что хотите перенести эти объекты в новую конфигурацию.

Если вы что-то изменяете в типовых объектах, то ведите реестр изменений. И после обновления заново ручками делайте свои изменения.

Comment: Спасибо большое, сделаю внешним отчетом!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы потом не было проблем с обновлением - нельзя.

Если вы включите возможность редактирования с сохранением поддержки, при обновлении вылезет [окно сравнения/слияния конфигураций](http://v8.1c.ru/overview/DeveloperCompUn.htm).

Comment: я просто думала, может, тогда сделать что-то типа внешнего отчета для этих документов, кот. просто будет выводить содержимое нужного файла.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас можно делать внешние печатные формы, но это есть не у всех конфигураций, надо проверять.